# How to extract certain <a> elements out of a div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm on a project that requires me to extract certain `<a>` elements (can be in Object type) from a div container. By using JavaScript, I'm able to get all `<a>` objects from the div. But the problem is, I only want the  objects in the "first level" of `<ul>`, not the ones contained in another `<ul>` within one of its `<li>`.

For example, in the code below, I only want AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD. Not CCC-sub1 nor CCC-sub2. How do I achieve this via javascript/jquery?

Help is highly appreciated! Thanks.

```
<div id="sampleList">

<ul>

<li>
<a href="a.html">AAA</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="b.html">BBB</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="c.html">CCC</a>

    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="c-sub1.html">CCC-Sub1</a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="c-sub2.html">CCC-Sub2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</li>


</li>
<a href="d.html">DDD</a>
</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. What do you mean by *Object type*? Also you should go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: BTW, you accidentally used `</li>` instead of `<li>` before your last link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged this jQuery:

```
$('#sampleList > ul > li > a');
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$(function(){
  var links = $('#samplelist>ul>li>a').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  alert(links);
});
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/ixayud/edit#javascript,html).